# What is the yarn equivalent to npm explore?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

`npm explore` is a command that allows you to execute commands within the context of a module directory.

What is the yarn equivalent of this command?

Answer (score 0):

Neither yarn [1.x](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/) nor [2.x](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/bin) have an equivalent command.